# How to check QEMU virtual machine filesystem without the user password

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, encryption, qemu

I'm doing a couple of tests of Ubuntu autoinstall using `cloud-init`. In order to do so, I am following an example that's presented in the [Autoinstall QuickStart](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart) page. In the given example, the presented password hash corresponds to the encrypted `ubuntu` passphrase and that works flawlessly. However, if I try to use my own encrypted hash, it doesn't seem to work (I can't login with the plain text password I feed the encryption algorithm with).

I know it probably has something to do with the encryption algorithm I'm using, but I think it should work and I would love to be able to check the `/etc/shadow` of the QEMU virtual machine to check what is being written there.

As per the example, I boot the VM with the following command:

```
kvm -no-reboot -m 2048 \
    -drive file=image.img,format=raw,cache=none,if=virtio
```

Is there a way to mount the filesystem of the VM to my local machine and check `/etc/shadow`?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `image.img` is indeed the image containing the Ubuntu root partition and it is indeed *raw*, things are very simple.

```
sudo losetup --find --show --partscan /path/to/image.img
# This will print something like /dev/loop0
sudo mount /dev/loop0p3 /mnt/ubuntu
```

You need to use the correct partition number, of course, which may not be `p3`.

Your version of `losetup` may not support `--partscan`. Instead, you can use `sudo partprobe /dev/loop0`. You can list partitions using `sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop0` (or using similar tools).

Once you’re done:

```
sudo umount /mnt/ubuntu
sudo losetup --detach /dev/loop0
```

If it’s a different image format, you may try *qemu-nbd* or *libguestfs-tools*, both of which I unfortunately have no experience with. If you’re using QEMU, you probably already have *qemu-nbd*.

Comment: Thanks for replying! However, after selecting the correct device and partition, I'm getting `mount: /mnt/ubuntu: special device /dev/loop3p3 does not exist.`. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Like I wrote: You may have to run `partprobe`. Also do make sure it’s the correct partition!

Comment: You need to use losetup `--partscan` to activate partition support for a loop device. It's not enabled by default.

Comment: @user1686 Interesting, I was not aware of this option. Maybe it’s a somewhat recent addition. I added it to the answer.

Comment: It's a 2011 addition, although I was wrong about "partition *support*" as it turns out the exact same commit also made it possible for partprobe etc. to manually add partitions even without kernel partition scanning being enabled.